# How to check all roles which are not assigned to any user but oracle default users (root, system, etc)?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a SQL for to get all the roles which are not being used by any custom (not default) oracle user or they are being used by users in a invalid state.
For me an invalid state means, a user which starts with `SRV_%` and has its status is different then `OPEN`.

The sql which I have so far, is this one:

```
with
  INVALID_USERS as
    (
      select
        USERNAME
      from
        DBA_USERS
      where
        USERNAME like 'SRV_%'
        and ACCOUNT_STATUS != 'OPEN'
    ),
  VALID_USERS as (
    select
      USERNAME
    from
      DBA_USERS
    where
      USERNAME not like 'SRV_%'
      and (not ACCOUNT_STATUS = 'LOCKED')
  )
select *
from
  DBA_ROLE_PRIVS drolp
  join DBA_ROLES drol ON drol.ROLE = drolp.GRANTED_ROLE
where
  GRANTEE in (select USERNAME from INVALID_USERS)
  and GRANTEE not in (select USERNAME from VALID_USERS);
```

Probably I need to use HAVING to remove the occurrences of valid users from invalid users role usage.
I'm stuck there.

Comment: Does valid and invalid both returned same user name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea whether your VALID_USER and INVALID_USER queries are right, since you haven't given us your requirements on those. But I think this is the problem with your main query:

```
with
  INVALID_USERS as
    (
      select
        USERNAME
      from
        DBA_USERS
      where
        USERNAME like 'SRV_%'
        and ACCOUNT_STATUS != 'OPEN'
    ),
  VALID_USERS as (
    select
      USERNAME
    from
      DBA_USERS
    where
      USERNAME not like 'SRV_%'
      and (not ACCOUNT_STATUS = 'LOCKED')
  )
select *
from
  DBA_ROLES drol
where
  -- role is assigned to AT LEAST ONE "invalid user"
  EXISTS (select 1 from DBA_ROLE_PRIVS drolp where drol.ROLE = drolp.GRANTED_ROLE and GRANTEE in (select USERNAME from INVALID_USERS))
  -- and role is not assigned to ANY "valid users"
  and NOT EXISTS (select 1 from DBA_ROLE_PRIVS drolp where drol.ROLE = drolp.GRANTED_ROLE and GRANTEE in (select USERNAME from VALID_USERS));
```

Your query's WHERE logic is checked once for each row in DBA_ROLE_PRIVS, and so GRANTEE will always be one value - one user. So it'll only return true for any GRANTEE  who is in both your VALID_USERS and INVALID_USERS - probably not what you want.

You need to query the DBA_ROLE_PRIVS table twice - once to check for valid users, and once to check for invalid users. You can get around that with aggregate functions, though you'd have to put your conditions outside the GROUP BY - make it a subquery or move them to a HAVING clause like this:

```
with
  INVALID_USERS as
    (
      select
        USERNAME
      from
        DBA_USERS
      where
        USERNAME like 'SRV_%'
        and ACCOUNT_STATUS != 'OPEN'
    ),
  VALID_USERS as (
    select
      USERNAME
    from
      DBA_USERS
    where
      USERNAME not like 'SRV_%'
      and (not ACCOUNT_STATUS = 'LOCKED')
  )
select GRANTED_ROLE
from
  DBA_ROLE_PRIVS drolp
  join DBA_ROLES drol on drol.ROLE = drolp.GRANTED_ROLE
group by GRANTED_ROLE
having
  -- role is assigned to AT LEAST ONE "invalid user"
  sum(CASE when GRANTEE in (select USERNAME from INVALID_USERS) THEN 1 else 0 end) > 0
  -- and role is not assigned to ANY "valid users"
  and sum(CASE when GRANTEE in (select USERNAME from VALID_USERS) THEN 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks your sql was what I was looking for. 
The only thing I added, I remove the users which contains all grants from VALID_USERS. Otherwise I would never get any info from this sql. 

VALID_USERS as (
    select
      USERNAME
    from
      DBA_USERS
    where
      (not ACCOUNT_STATUS = 'LOCKED')
      and USERNAME not in ('SYS','SYSTEM')
  )